# ggplot: combining size and color in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've only very recently started learning R. Now what I'm trying to do is to integrate two legends for the same plot. In other words, I want the default size legend to change color depending on it's size.

I have been Googling several solutions that apparently all don't seem to work, but again, I'm new to R so maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

My code:

```
ggplot(Caschool, aes(x=testscr, y=avginc), colour="green") +
  geom_point(aes(size=enrltot, color=enrltot)) +
  geom_smooth(colour="blue") +
  labs(x="Test Score", y="Average Income", title="California Test Score Data", color="Number of Students\nPer District") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="grey", size=0.4), 
    panel.background=element_rect(fill="beige"), 
    axis.line=element_line(size = 1.2, colour = "black"),
    plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2))) +
  scale_color_continuous(limits=c(0, 30000), breaks=seq(0,30000, by=2500)) +
  guides(color= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())
```

Apparently, I'm not allowed to post pictures, or I would have shown what this looks like so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you show a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Or at least add some of the data to your post, for instance by copy-pasting the output of dput(yourdata) or dput(yourdata,30) if it's large.

Comment: If you post a link with the picture, someone with more reputation can edit it in for you.

Comment: I have given you an answer that will hopefully be useful. Please take it also as input on how to formulate good questions. If you had created the plot with `mtcars`  or any other sample data set from R, anyone would have been able to reproduce your plot and solve your problem. There would not even have been a need to post a picture, because anyone could have looked at the result. Quite generally, the sample data sets in R are useful to create reproducible examples. Look at `?datasets` to get more information.

Comment: Hi, that makes a lot of sense. I will make examples with public datasets in the future! Someone already answered so I'll keep this just as reminder, but thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ggplot2` can indeed combine size and colour legends into one, however, this only works, if they are compatible: they need to have exactly the same breaks, otherwise they can not be combined.

Let me make an example: Assume, you have values between 0 and 10 that you want to map on size and colour. You tell `ggplo2` to use small points for values below 5 and large points for larger value. It will then plot a legend with a small and a large point, as expected. Now, you also want to add colour and you require points below 3 to be green and points above to be blue. `ggplot2` will also draw a legend for this, but it is impossible to combine the two legends. The small point would have to be both, green and blue. The problem can be solved by using the same breaks for colour and size.

In your example, you manually change the breaks of the colour scale, but not those of the size scale. This results in incompatible legends that can not be combined.

I can not demonstrate this using your date, because I don't have it. So I will create an example with `mtcars`. The variant with incompatible legends is constructed as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=drat)) +
   geom_point(aes(size=gear, color=gear)) +
   scale_color_continuous(limits=c(2, 5), breaks=seq(2, 5, by=0.5)) +
   guides(color= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())
```

which gives the following plot:

[image]

If I now add the same breaks for size,

```
p + scale_size_continuous(limits=c(2, 5), breaks=seq(2, 5, by=0.5))
```

I get a plot with only one legend:

[image]

For your code, this means that you should add the following to your plot:

```
+ scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0, 30000), breaks=seq(0,30000, by=2500))
```

A little side remark: What do you intend by using `colour = "green"` in your call to `ggplot`? I don't see that this has any effect at all, because you set the colour again in both geoms that you use later. Maybe a relic from an older variant of the plot?

Comment: Hi Stibu,

Thanks for the answer. At first it didn't work, but because of your explanation that you have to equalise the legends, I noticed I also had to add a name to labs: size="Number of Students\nPer District"

About the side remark. I have no idea either actually :) The University of Amsterdam just offered this course as a pre-PhD course so I'm simply doing assignments given to me at this point. When I started out fooling around with aesthetics I might have put it in there and since it gave no error, forgot about it afterwards!

Comment: Good work! I missed the trouble with the labs, because I omitted them in my example. Sorry about that!