# How to include bin size (value range) information in the legend of color/size of ggplot2 figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649426/ggplot-combining-size-and-color-in-legend), I learned how to combine size and color information into a single legend using `ggplot2`.
Here, I have an additional question regarding the legend:

Below is the baseline plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl, size=cyl)) +
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours=c('#762a83','white','white', '#35968f'),
    values=c(0,50,55,100)/100,#67,77
    limits=c(4,8),breaks=seq(4, 8, by=1))+
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(4, 8), breaks=seq(4, 8, by=1))+#
  guides(color= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend())
```

[image]

Here, I manually set the value range (4~8) and bin size (=1) using `limits` and `breaks`, and I want to include the bin size information in the legend. Specifically, the legend in the above plot shows "4", "5"..."8" with five symbols, and what I want is to show "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", & "7-8" with four symbols like below:

[image]

Would you please give me suggestions about making this happen?

I am looking forward to hearing about this.

Comment: My answer below is more like "faking" a range. The appropriate way to do it should be to apply some "binning" strategy (like `cut`) to your original dataframe prior to `ggplot`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about the "binning strategy". Would you please give me a code example for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut` to "bin" the `cyl` values upstream of `ggplot`.

- `colorRampPalette(c('#762a83','white', '#35968f'))(4)` generates a gradient of four colors using the supplied colors
- `scale_xxx_xxx(drop = FALSE)` to include missing values in the data (e.g. the `mtcars` dataset does not have a `cyl` range of "6-7", but we want that in the figure legend)

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars |> 
         mutate(
           cyl2 = cut(cyl, seq(min(cyl), max(cyl)), 
                      include.lowest = T, 
                      labels = paste0(min(cyl):(max(cyl) - 1), "-", (min(cyl) + 1):max(cyl)))
           ), 
       aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl2, size=cyl2)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=colorRampPalette(c('#762a83','white', '#35968f'))(4), drop = F, name = "cyl") +
  scale_size_discrete(drop = F, name = "cyl")
#> Warning: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>